# Bundle gem installed but reportedly not installed

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, installation, bundler

Bundler works for everything except when I call it myself. As you can see the gem is clearly installed. However, it appears as though it is not installed?

```
$ gem install bundler

Fetching: bundler-1.5.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.5.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.5.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.5.3...

$ apt-cache policy bundler

bundler:
  Installed: (none)

Candidate: 1.3.5-2

Version table:
    1.3.5-2 0
    500 http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/ testing/main i386 Packages
```

Whenever I try to use 'bundle install' it reports Bundler::GemFileNotFound

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you exactly what's wrong. You need a Gemfile with a list of gems in the directory you're running bundle install in. If you've created a rails project with: rails new my_project. cd into my_project and you will see a Gemfile there.

Comment: arg! Thanks so much. I am newer to ruby and forgot about that step and what it does